# continuous slider in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am very frustrated about this, because every method I found online does not work for me. Some can only display str rather then pass on variable. E.g.

```
h = uicontrol('style','slider','callback',@(src,evt)disp(get(src,'value')));
addlistener(h,'Value','PreSet',@(~,~)disp('hi'));
```

If I replace the disp function with my Callback, I get error saying there is no 'Value' property. Here is my code

```
zeta = .5;                           % Damping Ratio
wn = 2;                              % Natural Frequency
sys = tf(wn^2,[1,2*zeta*wn,wn^2]); 
f = figure;
ax = axes('Parent',f,'position',[0.13 0.39  0.77 0.54]);
h = stepplot(ax,sys);
setoptions(h,'XLim',[0,10],'YLim',[0,2]);
b = uicontrol('Parent',f,'Style','slider','Position',[81,54,419,23],...
              'value',zeta, 'min',0, 'max',1,'callback',@(s,e)updateSystem(h,tf(wn^2,[1,2*s.Value*wn,wn^2])));
addlistener(b,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e)updateSystem(h,tf(wn^2,[1,2*s.Value*wn,wn^2])))
```

"No appropriate method, property, or field 'Value' for class 'matlab.graphics.internal.GraphicsMetaProperty'."

In other example, there is 'ContinuousValueChange', 'ActionEvents', which simply does not work.

Can anyone give me a simple example where slider give continuous output on its value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your listener line the variable `s` is the listener object not the uicontrol variable (b).

Updating your simple example it would be:

```
figure;
h = uicontrol('style','slider','callback',@(src,evt)disp(get(src,'value')));
addlistener(h,'Value','PreSet',@(~,~)disp(h.Value));
```